# Making a call to a SOAP service with php

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Hi I am new to SOAP and I manage to create a webservice with asp.net that contains a method called GetPersons.The service is tested and it works.

My problem is consuming it with php.this is what I hae so far:

```
 $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:55400/Convert.asmx?WSDL");
 $client->__soapCall("GetPersons");
```

This throws an error telling me that __soapCall expects a second arguments parameter but mu GetPersons method has no arguments.

I have also tested to see if PHP gets any methods from the link like this:

```
 print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```

This is what I get back:

```
Array ( [0] => GetPersonsResponse GetPersons(GetPersons $parameters) [1] => GetPersonsResponse GetPersons(GetPersons $parameters) )
```

So how can I make the call to my GetPersons method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://localhost:55400/Convert.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($url);

$xmlr = new SimpleXMLElement("<Get></Get>");
$xmlr->addChild('searchtxt', $_GET['searchtxt']);

$params = new stdClass();
$params->xml = $xmlr->asXML();

$result = $client->GetPersons($params);
```

You need to read the documentation about what parameters to pass.

Related:

- [Sending XML input to WSDL using SoapClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595789/sending-xml-input-to-wsdl-using-soapclient)