# calling .NET Web service from PHP

Tags: php, .net, soap-client

I tested in visual studio MyWebService.asmx and it works.

When I run it from the php page, I get exception in visual studio parameter not supplied.
I guess there is something wrong with the php code.

```
<?php 
    $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:1144/MyWebService.asmx?WSDL");
    $arr = $client->PhpWebMethod($_GET['searchtxt']);
    print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://localhost:1144/MyWebService.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($url);

$xmlr = new SimpleXMLElement("<Get></Get>");
$xmlr->addChild('searchtxt', $_GET['searchtxt']);

$params = new stdClass();
$params->xml = $xmlr->asXML();

$result = $client->PhpWebMethod($params);
```

Related:

- [Sending XML input to WSDL using SoapClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595789/sending-xml-input-to-wsdl-using-soapclient)