# What is 'any' in wsdl and how i can call a wsdl function using php?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

This code is a small part of my wsdl. Here I haven't understood

```
<s:sequence>
    <s:any/>
</s:sequence>
```

Please tell me what is this

```
<s:element name="CalculStudents">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="doc">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

using php I am calling this function  below is my code

```
 $client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");
 $params = array("any"=>'');
 $result = $client->CalculStudents(array('doc'=>$params));
```

but it's throwing an error

```
 Exception Error! Server was unable to process 
 request.Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Tell me how to solve this. Is this a php calling mistake or wsdl is wrong?

Comment: please help me to solve this

Comment: here CalculStudents is method and doc is a parameter up to that i understand but tell me what is any/

Comment: are you sure CalculStudents is the input method?  Looks like a result or response which might explain the error if you are trying to trigger it directly.

Comment: look at your whole wsdl and ensure you have a binding with that operation `<wsdl:operation name="CalculStudents">`

Comment: hi this is the actual webservice that client given i dont understand what is the mistake

Comment: You should post the full wsdl or provide the URL for it

Comment: @Athi i am not sure what you have to pass for that function, but the error you are getting is server-side, so it's not your fault, an invalid param may cause this, but this means the server-side is not well-built, to handle exceptions and validate inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In XML Schema, [the `any` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#element-any) is a way of specifying "any non-empty sequence of elements at all".

So the WSDL you have is saying, "This method can accept any data at all, and can potentially return any data at all." This is obviously completely bogus, and you're little better off than you would have been *without* a WSDL. Your only recourse at this point is to yell at the API vendor and pray you eventually get useful documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:any>
  id = xs:ID
  maxOccurs = ( xs:nonNegativeInteger | “unbounded” ) : “1”
  minOccurs = xs:nonNegativeInteger : “1”
  namespace = ( (“##any” |  “##other” ) | list of (xs:anyURI | “##targetNamespace” | “##local”) ) ) : “##any”
  processContents = (“skip” | “lax” | “strict”) : “strict”

##any: any element from any namespace
##other: any element from any namespace other than the target
##targetNamespace: any element from the target
```

skip: do not attempt validation of these elements (by looking for schema)
lax : attempt validation but don’t complain if you can’t find schema
strict: attempt validation and error if you can’t find schema

```
$params = array("id"=>'',"maxOccurs"=>'',"minOccurs"=>'',"namespace"=>'',"processContents"=>'');
  $result = $client->__soapCall("CalculStudents",array("any"=>$params));
```

Comment: In message i have given the full actual wsdl file

Comment: Please pass a value to the doc parameter, do you have an example of a "doc" value?

Comment: In webservice its specifying <any>

Comment: <wsdl:types> <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="tempuri.org/">; <s:element name="CalculComposition"> <s:complexType> <s:sequence> <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="doc"> <s:complexType mixed="true"> <s:sequence> <s:any/> </s:sequence> </s:complexType> </s:element> </s:sequence> </s:complexType> </s:element>

Comment: Instead of CalculStudents here  CalculComposition

Comment: then try the above code with any as param (this with a question mark from my behalf) and CalculComposition instead of CalculStudents. Also check the schema of another WSDL http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl just to get some ideas yourself. I just think that any is not a parameter or there is some issue with the schema.

Comment: tell me what is this </any>

Comment: You can try using the SOAP UI client app that (if it can) will parse the WSDL doc and try to construct some example request envelopes. Very helpful when it works but can be a bit fussy http://www.soapui.org/. There are others to test with as well

Comment: Check this regarding "any". http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.cs.uchicago.edu%2F~asiegel%2Fcourses%2Fcspp51038%2Fnotes%2FWSDL.ppt&ei=0qCjVPmFEoP0UNjEgKAL&usg=AFQjCNHLZtlktoW5Tqighqm4ijs_bXiM-A&bvm=bv.82001339,d.d24